# Rospack Error Eigen missing

Tags: eigen, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, rosmake, hand-interaction

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is running on Ubuntu 12.04 in a virtualbox on windows7

I'm trying to make the hand_interaction package for kinect, but it won't compile.

Here's my error:

---

> mkdir -p bin   cd build && cmake -Wdev
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..   --
> Eigen found (include:
> /usr/include/eigen3)   [rosbuild]
> Building package hand_interaction
> Failed to invoke
> /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack
> deps-manifests hand_interaction
> [rospack] Error: package/stack
> hand_interaction depends on
> non-existent package eigen
>
> ```
>  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:133
> ```
>
> (message):
>
> ```
> Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
> 'hand_interaction'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
> ```
>
> Aborting.
> Please fix the broken dependency!

---

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38297/rospack-error-eigen-missing/) by [GLaDOS_9000](https://answers.ros.org/users/2799/glados_9000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to compile a package in Fuerte that hasn't been updated for it yet. Eigen is not part of Fuerte anymore. You could try to remove the dependency on it from hand_interaction's manifest.xml file but you can expect more problems.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-09**:
If you want to develop a patch for hand_interaction, here is the migration guide: http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration#Eigen_can.27t_be_found

**Comment by [GLaDOS_9000](https://answers.ros.org/users/2799/glados_9000/) on 2012-07-09**:
I'm just trying to get it to run, I don't know enough about it to make a patch... DX But thanks I guess :/

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-09**:
If you can't fix it yourself, try contacting the developers. I don't see any bug reporting links for that stack, so maybe it is not actively maintained.